# If I attach a callback to object.ngOnDestroy() will that overwrite its internal onDestroy() method?

Tags: angular

I'm extending the drag and drop functionality of Angular

```html
<div cdkDropList appEnhancedDropList>
  <div cdkDrag>item 1</div>
  <div cdkDrag>item 2</div>
  <div cdkDrag>item 3</div>
</div>
```

My `appEnhancedDropList` directive needs to access the `cdkDrag` elements that are contained inside the `cdkDropList` and add a bunch of event listeners:

```js
export class EnhancedDropListDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  ...

  @ContentChildren(CdkDrag) dragItems!: QueryList<CdkDrag>
  
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    // Add the functionality we need to each of the child cdkDrag 
    // components
    this.dragItems.toArray().map(item => {
      const subs: Subscription[] = [] 

      // Add the event handlers we need
      subs.push(dragItem.dropped.subscribe(this.onDragDrop))
      subs.push(dragItem.released.subscribe(this.onDragRelease))

      // Make sure the subscriptions are destroyed when the dragItem
      // is destroyed
      dragItem.ngOnDestroy = () => { // CAN I DO THIS?
        subs.map(sub => sub.unsubscribe())
      }
    })
  }
}
```

### Can I safely add the ngOnDestroy() to the CdkDrag?

I know that I *can* add `ngOnDestroy` to each of the `cdkDrag` components however I'm not sure whether that will overwrite its own internal implementation of `ngOnDestroy` (which I obv don't want to do).

If I can't safely add it is there any other way to monitor its destruction so I can unsubscribe accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

You could patch the method

```js
const original = dragItem.ngOnDestroy
dragItem.ngOnDestroy = () => {
   subs.map(sub => sub.unsubscribe())
   original.call(dragItem)
}
```

As an aside, you might want to use `forEach` here rather than `map` as you're not assigning the returned array: `toArray().map`

Comment: that's a really clean suggestion. Good lateral thinking :)

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately it doesn't work. Test show that the `ngOnDestroy` method isn't being called at all...